# How can i get location name using LAC(location area code)

Tags: android, locationmanager

after a lot of research i fond that LAC can be used in location based applications for finding Location.i have a few questions about LAC1)what information do i get from LAC ? 2)How can i find name of a location using LAC? 3)is there any website or database to know about LAC of my location?
i don't need codes,i need answers of these questions,plese help me

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for getting the cell tower info :

```
public static void getCellTowerInfo() {

        TelephonyManager mTelephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) POContext.getContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        GsmCellLocation location = (GsmCellLocation) mTelephonyManager.getCellLocation();
        if (location != null) {
            // cell id of the
            POGlobals.PhoneInfo.CellID = String.valueOf(location.getCid());
            Log.i(POGlobals.TAG, "CellID of the Device-->" + POGlobals.PhoneInfo.CellID);
            // get theLAC
            POGlobals.PhoneInfo.LAC = String.valueOf(location.getLac());
            Log.i(POGlobals.TAG, "LAC of the Device-->" + POGlobals.PhoneInfo.LAC);
        }
        if (mTelephonyManager != null) {
            // get the combination of MNC+MCC for the GSM Networks only
            if (mTelephonyManager.getNetworkOperator() != null && mTelephonyManager.getNetworkOperator().length() > 0) {
                POGlobals.PhoneInfo.MCC = mTelephonyManager.getNetworkOperator().substring(0, 3);
                POGlobals.PhoneInfo.MNC = mTelephonyManager.getNetworkOperator().substring(3);
                mTelephonyManager.getNetworkType();
            } else {
                // Phone is in Airplane Mode situation
                Logger.e(POGlobals.TAG, "TelephonyManager service is NULL");
            }
        }
    }
```

Please remove the Compilation error of the logger and global variables.

LAC is location area code which is given by the Service provider and which is depends on your nearest tower.

Comment: This LAC will return you the code which is integer. if you wanted to compare the actual location which is string you need to do the reverse geo coding of the Latitude and Longitude. so you will get the location till steet name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [OpenCellID's API](http://www.opencellid.org/api) to get the location using MCC, MNC, LAC and CellID.